# My capacitor charger LT3751 does not charge

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, charging

I built the below [LT3751](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT3751.pdf) capacitor charger, but unfortunately it is not working.

The capacitors are not charging and I don't see any dynamic signal at any of the chip pins.

- The FAULT pin is in high state - 5 V.
- The DONE pin is also in high state.
- No switching pulses on HVgate, nor on RBG.

[image]

Comment: \$\overline{\text{FAULT}}\$ when 5 volts indicates good/OK.

Comment: How are you simulating? What initial conditions? For how long? How is that transformer configured? Have you checked *everything* against the datasheet?

Comment: Hi, this is not about simulation but I already have the prototype on my hands. The initial conditions are as seen in the schematic - 22V @Vtrans,VCC and 5V@CHARGE. The transformer is recommended by Linear. I indeed checked everything I can against the datasheet. I also ran simulation which was OK.

Answer (score 0):

Transformer is backwards, for one thing.

Comment: Can you comment about the state of the rest of the circuit?

Comment: The transformer is also not backwards. This is exactly how the datasheet recommends connecting it, and the pin labels match the GA3459's datasheet.